# How to remove white gap between two skewed images?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I want to have two parts of one image to be join into one original image, where each one part should be a triangle form.

I've found a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Halws/pen/mLWoEd) where there are two elements with nested images, where i removed margins, but there is an ugly white border(gap) between elements.

How can i remove this one?

[image: image with white border]

---

```
<div class='pageOption'>
  <a href='#' class='option' data-inf='photo'>
    <img src='http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2013-06-a-large_web.jpg'>
  </a>
  <a href='#' class='option' data-inf='cinema'>
    <img src='http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2013-06-a-large_web.jpg'>
  </a>
</div>
```

---

```
body { background: gainsboro; }
.pageOption {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 40em; height: 27em;
}
.option, .option img { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
.option {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;  
  /* arctan(27 / 40) = 34.01935deg 
   * need to skew by 90deg - 34.01935deg = 55.98065deg
  */
  transform: skewX(-55.98deg);
}
.option:first-child {
/*   left: -.25em; */
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
}
.option:last-child {
/*   right: -.25em; */
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
.option img { opacity: 1; transition: .5s; }
.option img:hover { opacity: 1; }
.option img, .option:after {
  transform: skewX(55.98deg);
  transform-origin: inherit;
}
.option:after {
  position: absolute;
  margin: .5em 1.65em;
  color: white;
  font: 500 1.25em Courier;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  content: attr(data-inf);
}
.option:first-child:after { top: 0; left: 0; }
.option:last-child:after { right: 0; bottom: 0; }
```

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma does't help, it just hide element

Comment: If you set left and right to zero in the example you gave you get it gapless, but the slight white artefact (on Mac at least) is a result of the opacity showing the background color, if you set the body to black it appears gapless:
https://codepen.io/NeilWkz/pen/yjMrMZ

Comment: moving `.option:last-child` 1px to the right removed the gap https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ervoxN

Comment: @NeilWkz it's definitely less visible, but still not ideal solution for one image

Comment: @Taki your solution is quite similar as Nandita Arora Sharma  suggested below, but it have the same problem with  moved out corners  [image](http://prntscr.com/jcdcjq)

Answer (score 0):

Change these styles

```
.option:first-child {
  left: 0.1em;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
}
.option:last-child {
  right: 0;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
```

Comment: Moving the left a bit, will allow the right part to show on the bottom left corner, thought of something alike this by applying `margin-left: 1px` to the right side, but you get the same problem.